# Where do this Webservice ASMX belongs? (DAL)

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I'm about to manage an application that has a clint with a web presentation layer. Which have a webservice as it's data source. Where do I have to place the ASMX in the client app? Today are this asmx pointing directly into the web presentation layer, which feels little spooky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a public website and the world isn't supposed to have access to the web services, it's a good idea to deploy the data access webservices behind the firewall in another IIS site (preferably on a different server) so the services aren't available to the world.

If this is an internal website and there are internal clients that should be able to hit the services, this becomes more of an architectural than security question.  In this case, it's still nice to separate the web project from the services project (but in this case it's not as big of a deal of they're served from the same server).

Comment: I see.. thats completely answer/confirms my thoughts (its an public accessible asmx). One thing though.. has the guy really act reasonable on  adding the asmx in the clients web presentation layer? (its a customer demo web) which also had a business and data layer (without data conne'tion - it just bring down data from asmx in the presentation layer)

Comment: I still thinks it makes sense to separate the two projects (but can still be served from the same server).  That way, they can be maintained separately (for example, the services side could be upgraded to WCF without touching the presentation code).

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. I'm confused here. Im not on his way and are pleased to sepsrate all external concerns regarding api-alike calls into server, like this. Personally I  cant find a reasonable idea having such service at web layer. Though, im not fully sure regarding the client side?